# How to implement functionality in Android Such that i can record through bluetooth mic and play it on the phones speaker/headphones

Tags: android

I am trying to implement an IOT project for which I need to hear sound from a Bluetooth mic and play it on headphones paired to phone how could i achieve this functionality in Android Studio, also I need to save the media to perform an algorithmic research on it

Comment: What have you tried so far. Add your code effort and explain the problem you are facing .

Comment: I was trying to write code to redirect audio recorded through MediaRecorder class to give output in real time but I am facing problem on how to achieve it as MediaRecorder class saves the audio it hears my question is how can i play it in real time in function startListening() itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Solved]** This functionality could easily be achieved using Android libraries [AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord) and [AudioTrack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack) as they work on raw data, These libraries are mostly used for analysing real time data of audiostreams.